# Query an child in an array of objects in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to find an element of an array field in my firestore collection.

This is the field in firestore:

```
channels: [{name: "linkedin", date: "2020-01-02"}]
```

This is how I tried querying it:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("users")
  .where("status", "==", "ACTIVE")
  .where("channels", "array-contains", {
      name: "linkedin"                     
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array-contains` can`t perform search into objects specific values for properties.

it would work if you do something like `channels: ["Linkedin", "facebook", "twitter"]`

Probably you want to try to use a subcollection for channels instead, otherwise, you need to fetch all the values into channels and then apply filters in memory.